# Module compiled with Swift 5.0 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1 compiler:

Tags: swift, xcode, audiokit

Getting this error while import `AudioKit` in my new project in XCODE 11 latest version.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1860). I hope it will be useful.

Answer (score -2):

Unless you need Swift 5.1 or something specific to Xcode 11, I'd recommend staying on Xcode 10.x and moving over device support files so you can debug on iOS 13 devices.

https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

Or, if you've already downloaded Xcode 11.x, just move everything you want from

`/Applications/{XCODE11}.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`

to

`/Applications/{XCODE10}.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`

This is probably better advice for someone like me stuck using a closed source module built in Swift 5.0, but you're the first SO result on Google for this error message.